# Laptop wireless no longer connecting to Wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-card

I have a MSi u200, and the weird thing was that I was using this normally before, then after a few minutes all of a sudden it couldn't find the wifi signal from my house. I did some troubleshooting and a bit of search in the control panel, and it seems like my hardware is missing. :(

I can't even turn on the wireless light using Fn+F8, so my suspicions about the missing hardware strengthened. I tried searching for DIY fixes, but I found out that the wireless card is actually built-in deeper, unlike the RAM cards and the hard drive where you can either replace or add more cards. What do I do??

As of the moment, I can get connected to my wifi here at home using a wireless adapter via usb, and it's working. So my guess about the hardware problem seems correct.

What could cause this? Is it fixable?